# Variable of variable in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to access variables which is defined in `group_vars`

group_vars/all

```
parent1:
  child1: somevalue1
  child2: somevalue2

parent2:
  child1: somevalue1
  child2: somevalue2
```

Now I am passing `parent` detail from ansible playbook extra vars like 
 this

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "parent=parent1"
```

Now How can I access `parent1.child1` value where `parent1` comes in `{{ parent }}` vars?

My playbook look like this:-

playbook.yml

```
- hosts: local
  user: roop
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars: 
     parent: ""

  tasks: 

  #get parent value
  - debug: msg={{ parent }}

  #trying to access parent1.child1 value here
  - debug: msg={{ {{ parent }}.child1 }}
```

Playbook output:-

```
PLAY [local] ******************************************************************

TASK: [debug msg=local] *******************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "parent1"
}

TASK: [debug msg={{{{parent}}.child1}}] ***************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "{{{{parent}}.child1}}"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Can anyone guide how can I achieve this or any alternate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I have done this

Change group_vars/all like below:-

```
data:
    parent1:
      child1: somevalue1
      child2: somevalue2

    parent2:
      child1: somevalue1
      child2: somevalue2
```

Change in playbook.yml:-

```
 - debug: msg={{ data[parent].child1 }}
```

Please share if you have any better solution :)